# sed parameters from a function?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I tried to use the parameter for sed from a function as below.
If 'a' is found, then insert # before 'a' then append 'a' to next line.
The parama has same content as paramb, but I don't understand why sed command with paramb failed.
It seems the newline character returned from the function is trimmed?
The error message is "sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unterminated `s' command"

Please help, thanks.

```
parama="-e s/a/#&\n&/g"
echo "a" | sed $parama


test (){
    echo "-e s/a/#&\n&/g"
}

paramb=$(test)

echo "a" | sed $paramb
```

Comment: You shouldn't be able to define a function called `function` like this in `bash`, since it is a reserved word.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should do it like this:

```
parama="-e s/a/#&\n&/g"
echo "a" | sed $parama


function test(){
    echo "-e s/a/#&\n&/g";
}

paramb=$(test);

echo "a" | sed $paramb
```

You're not naming your function and I've named it as test.Output I'm getting:

```
$ ./testso2.sh 
#a
a
#a
a
```

Comment: thanks, but it's a problem of the function name, it failed with "test" as function name too.

Comment: @timchen what output you're expecting?

Comment: It turns out to be a problem of shell, it is all fine with bash, but not /bin/sh(is /bin/dash actually)

Answer (score 0):

it seems like a problem of shell, my script running well with bash, but not /bin/sh which is /bin/dash actually. My problem is now fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce a difference. It could be that your `echo` happens to interpret `\n`. Try:

```
printf "%s\n" "-e s/a/#&\n&/g"
```